# how to fix error creating a bootable USB stick of ubuntu-16.04 iso image?

Tags: 16.04, debug

Could you please help me to fix the bug (An uncaught exception was raised: invalid version string 'fn\x81\xe6\xe1\x8b\xef\xa3\xa861\xa6\xef') getting on creating a bootable USB stick of ubuntu 16.04 desktop iso image at 56% of  installation?

I am using ''Startup disk creator'' application.
I did md5sums but the result is '' warning: 1 computed checksum did not match''.
I am using 12.04 LTS version of ubuntu to create USB stick.

Comment: What software are you using to create the bootable USB stick? If you could edit your question to include that information, it would be helpful.

Comment: Also, have you verified the MD5 sum of the .iso file you downloaded? This helps verify that the file downloaded without errors or corruption (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM )

Comment: If the md5sum did not match, download the ISO again, recheck it until it matches.  What version of Ubuntu are you using to run startup disk creator, older ones like 14.04 do not work for 16.04.

Comment: what always works is 'UNetbootin', download it and create the bootable USB stick with it

Answer (score 0):

As the others said:

1. Make sure your ISO downloaded okay by checking the MD5 sum, if it didn't download it again
2. You can't use older versions of Ubuntu to make a bootable USB for the newer versions

That being said you could try opening Terminal and running the command:

```
sudo dd if=~/Downloads/ubuntu-x-x-x.iso of=/dev/yourUsb bs=4m && sync
```

Obviously substituting the path to the ISO and path to your USB.
You should be able to get the path to the USB in the Disks application.